# ASP.Net Membership in SQL vs. Windows

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-membership

I just inherited a project for a small company.  This is a completely internal web application and the current model for authentication and roleManager is based on their domain policies.  Well, I work from home and little experience with windows authentication, and I definitely am not part of a domain.

So, in order to "fake" the same sort of setup that they have, is it a good idea to setup ASP.Net Membership in SQL Server?  And I think that you can setup roles in there, too, which I could use to create a one-one mapping of roles in SQL to what they have on their network (there are 5 or so, that's all), correct?

Then, when I push changes to their system, I would just overwrite my web.config with one specific to them, that basically sets Membership auth and rolemanager to user their network setting instead of my SQL ones.  This would let me test locally but they could keep their domain driven security model.

Am I crazy, and these 2 things just aren't analogous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two things aren't the same so you're not going to be able to work on it as you are thinking. The membership provider would always require a login process and other user management, and the code to check the role membership and user account details would be completely different.

My suggestion would be to see if they have VPN access to their LAN and get them to set you up an account on the domain.

Comment: Thanks Ira -- I'll try that, but I'm also going to try to mock up the roles thing for fun.  I'm waiting on some info from them for other things, so I have time to play.  I promise I'll revisit this question and either accept yours if it ends up not working, or updating it with a solution if one pops up.

Comment: No probs. Take a look at this series of articles for a good background on it: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx